# How to upload dSYMs to Firebase using upload-symbols?

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics, xcode11

Trying to upload dSYMs file on firebase but after successful, always showikng missing dSYMs
I run the below command on terminal

```
/Users/apple/Documents/Global\ Name/MIHIN2.0/Pods/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols -gsp /Users/apple/Documents/Global\ Name/MIHIN2.0/GoogleService-Info.plist -p ios /Users/apple/Desktop/dSYMs
```

Kindly help me.

Comment: What is the result of this command you're running? Are you sure you're including the right path to the dSYMs and the GoogleServices-Info.plist file? We need more info as to what you're seeing in order to troubleshoot

Comment: yes I put right path, after run the command:
"Successfully uploaded Crashlytics symbols"

Comment: Please try running `dwarfdump -u /path/to/dSYM` and verify that the outputted ID is the same as the dSYM ID missing as displayed in your Firebase console. If it is, reach out to Firebase support as it will require more troubleshooting.

Comment: Getting below error:
>dwarfdump -u /Users/apple/Desktop/dSYM  then getting the below error,

error: /Users/apple/Desktop/dSYM: Is a directory